# Error in beamer: \QTR{frametitle}{Title Here}

Tags: beamer, scientific-workplace

I am trying to compile a beamer document that was originally written in scientific workplace. I am using WinEdt instead.

There are several things that do not seem portable from one compiler to the other. I have managed to fix most of these but not all.

One such thing is this:

```
\begin{frame}%
%EndExpansion

\QTR{frametitle}{title here}

\end{frame}
```

I get the following error:

```
[1{C:/Users/bla/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
! Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@doifinframe ...eamer@frameslide}\par \QTR 
                                                  {frametitle}{ title here...
l.62 \end{frame}
                %
?
```

Of course I know I can fix this by doing:

```
\begin{frame}{title here}%
%EndExpansion


\end{frame}
```

But I really wanted to avoid that as doing that for >200 slides is terrible. 
Is there a workaround? Some package that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can define the command `\QTR` so that it produces the frame title.  There are two ways to enter the frame title in beamer:

```
\begin{frame}{title here} 
... 
\end{frame}
```

or

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title here} 
... 
\end{frame}
```

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\providecommand\QTR[2]{\csname #1\endcsname{#2}}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}%
%EndExpansion

\QTR{frametitle}{title here}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```